# PHP Ajax Jquery UTF8 character issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have issue with get data from php and display data using the method of ajax.

My main index1.php file have  div where all data is display:

```
 <div  id="divPageData"> </div>
```

there is another tablepage.php where is ajax calling the script

```
function loadData()
 {
var dataString;
var search = $("input#fieldSearch").val();
var record = $("select#pageRecord").val();
var gender = $("select#fieldSearch1").val(); 
var colf = $("select#fieldcollege").val(); 
var deptf = $("select#fielddepartment").val();
var natf = $("select#fieldnationality").val();
var fstatusf = $("select#fieldfinalstatus").val();
var fyearf = $("select#fieldyear").val();   

dataString = '&name='+ search + '&gender=' + gender + '&colf=' + colf + '&deptf=' + deptf + '&natf=' + natf + '&fstatusf=' + fstatusf +  '&fyearf=' + fyearf +'&perpage=' + record;
//dataString = 'starting='+page+'&name='+search+'&gender='+ gender+'&perpage='+ record+'&random='+Math.random();

  $.ajax({
  url: "tablepage.php",
  type: "GET",
  data: dataString,
  success:function(data)
  {
    $('#divPageData').html(data);
  }
        });
```

For php i have use

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and as well i use

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and for mysql connection i use

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

and for ajax i use

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
```

and all data display correctly. even fetching data from mysql. But data inside "divPageData" is not display correctly (Sample display data: Ù‡Ø¯Ù‰ Ø¹Ø¨Ø¯Ø§Ù„ÙƒØ±ÙŠÙ… Ù…Ø­Ù…Ø¯ Ø¨Ù† Ø¹Ù„Ù‰)

[image: screenshot]

One more thing: Its working perfectly in Mozila firefox but i am facing problem in Google Chrome & IE.

Comment: Did you try using your Developer Tools to see if the XHR request responds with what you are expecting?

Comment: Yes i tried it and i am getting this error: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. jquery.min.js:137 ( And this error came on content type)

Comment: Please check if you are using an up to date version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded
>   notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual
>   form controls, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>`: **$( "input,
>   textarea, select" ).serialize();**

Change `dataString` to **`$( '#formid' ).serialize()`**

To store arabic data use below `contentType` in ajax

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
```

`Php file`

```
header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

**Declare encoding META tag, it causes browser to load the UTF-8 charset 
   before displaying the page.**

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

What code viewing programm are you using (notpad++, sublime ect.)? I had a problem where i saved my php file in different encouding style maybe you have the same problem.

Comment: i have created all php file through Dreamweaver use the default encoding UTF-8 character

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your MySqli database tables have not been configured with UTF-8??

Comment: If you see the image, the combo-box fetch correct data from database.

Answer (score 0):

3 reasons i can think of

1. there is a BOM character on top of your tablepage.php page. Read more on this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
2. Your mysql table for those data is not configured correctly for utf8.
3. You double-encode/decode the data. Verify that there is only one utf8 conversion of the data. Try to remove the php header or the ajax charset and see what happens